# Web Scraping/ Web Crawling

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Can somebody help me figure out how to scrape / crawl this website? https://www.arkansasonline.com/i/lrcrime/

I've downloaded the page source, with `requests` and parced with `BeautifulSoup`, but I can't figure out what's going on.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#####################################################
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url     = 'https://www.arkansasonline.com/i/lrcrime/'
r       = requests.get(url, headers = headers).text
soup    = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser' ) 

data    = [x.get_text() for x in soup.find_all('td')] 

#####################################################
```

Typically this would do the trick and I'd get a list of all table data inputs..

But I'm getting

```
['SEARCH | DISPATCH LOG | STORIES | HOMICIDES | OLD MAP',
 '\n\n\n\nClick here to load this Caspio Cloud Database\nCloud Database by Caspio\n']
```

Which is far from what I need....

Also, how do I craw the 3000 pages?

I also tried to do it with a macro and just record my keystrokes and save to google drive, but the page moves around as you go through the pages, so it makes that basically impossible.  They are trying to hide the crime data In my opinion.  I want to scrape it all into 1 database and release it to the public.

Comment: Do you have a set of demo creds to login for us to test?

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Most of content is provided dynamically, so you won't get it with `requests`, only the first table with some navigation is provided static, thats why you get this as result.

There is also a "big" hint you should respect.

> ***This Content is Only Available to Subscribers.***

#### How to fix?

**NOTE:** *Be kind and subscribe to consume the content - would be the best solution.*

Assuming this is the case you should go with `selenium` that will render the page as a browser will do and also provide the table you are looking for.

You have to wait until the table is loaded:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table[data-cb-name="cbTable"]')))
```

Grab the `page_source` and load it with `pandas` as dataframe.

#### Example (selenium 4)

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

service = Service(executable_path='ENTER YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get('https://www.arkansasonline.com/i/lrcrime/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table[data-cb-name="cbTable"]')))
pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[1]
```

#### Output

| INCIDENT NUMBER | OFFENSE DESCRIPTION | Location/address | ZIP | INCIDENT DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-134824 | ALL OTHER LARCENY | 8109 W 34TH ST | 72204 | 11/1/2021 |
| 2021-134815 | BURGLARY/B&E | 42 NANDINA LN | 72210 | 11/1/2021 |
| 2021-134790 | ROBBERY | 1800 BROADWAY ST | 72206 | 11/1/2021 |
| 2021-134788 | AGGRAVATED ASSAULT | 11810 PLEASANT RIDGE RD | 72223 | 11/1/2021 |
| 2021-134778 | THEFT FROM MOTOR VEHICLE | 4 HANOVER DR | 72209 | 11/1/2021 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |